# Run one MS Access SQL script on a particular Table chosen by user

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet-sql

I have a MS Access 2016 database (*.accdb) with 20+ Tables. Fields in each of them vary slightly from Table to Table. I've no VBA experience, so I'm sticking only to the SQL query below (redacted).

### SQL script

*myvar* below is the parameter I'd like to be prompted when the script is run so that I enter the Table I want the changes applied to.

```
PARAMETERS 
[myvar] TableID;

UPDATE 
[myvar]

INNER JOIN  
Excel_Data ON [myvar].[Part Number] = Excel_Data.[Part Number] 

SET 
[myvar].[Value] = '?', 
[myvar].Description = Excel_Data.Description, 
[myvar].[Ref] = '?'
.
.
.

WHERE 
[myvar].Description Is Null;
```

### Output

Error message:

```
Too few parameters. Expected 0.
```

### What I need

I prefer a solution for above in a SQL script form as above, not involving VBA, preferably. I'd like to enter the Table name when prompted so the script knows which table to UPDATE. FYI: The PARAMETERS work when it is not a Table as I've shown in my script above.

Help/advise is highly appreciated.

### EDIT 1

Since it seems not possible to use parameters as Table names, could you suggest a VBA solution? A sample code, perhaps?

Comment: You can't use parameters for table names, period. Needing to use dynamic table names indicates a non-normalized design. The only way to deal with it is through VBA, and I don't recommend integrating VBA in your application if you have 0 experience with it and can't interpret or adjust the code you get in an answer.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I have to use VBA. I'll learn. Could you suggest a VBA code snippet for me? I'll edit the questions accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can't really solve this without VBA.

You can store your SQL query in a string, and use a placeholder to indicate the tablename. Then get the tablename using an inputbox and replace the placeholder with the tablename.

```
Dim sqlString As String
sqlString = "UPDATE [%Placeholder%] "  & vbCrLf & _
"INNER JOIN Excel_Data ON [%Placeholder%].[Part Number] = Excel_Data.[Part Number]  "  & vbCrLf & _
"SET [%Placeholder%].[Value] = '?', " & vbCrLf & _
...
"WHERE [%Placeholder%].Description Is Null;"
sqlString = Replace(sqlString, "%PlaceHolder%", InputBox("Enter a tablename"))
CurrentDb.Execute sqlString
```

In a more mature solution, I'd create a form with a combobox containing all available table names, and add a function to sanitize tablenames (replace "]" with "]]")

Comment: Thanks. Works! I Put the entire thing on to a Form and pimped it up a bit to read input directly from text entry boxes.